Usage of Single timer for multiple triggers among various popups
I have 5 different popup's that displays 5 different properties all these 5  properties need to be checked periodically from CPP in order to update if there is any change in the value of property. At present i am using 5 different timers for checking the 5 different properties on periodic basis. Is there a way to use a single timer for achieving the same in Qt/CPP/QML.
Any suggestions are appreciated.
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

   
   Item {
       width:1920
       height: 1080
       Popupone {
           id:popup1
           visible:false
           anchors.centerIn:parent
           // Connect the signal to a function
          
       }
   }
   Item{
       width:1920
       height: 1080
       Popuptwo{
           id:popup2
           visible:false
           anchors.centerIn:parent
       }
   }
   Timer {
       id:timer
       interval:1000
       running:false
       repeat:true
       onTriggered: {
           // this fun will call every second
           communicationbwleapHMI.getfuns();
       }
   }
   Timer {
       id:timer1
       interval:1000
       running:false
       repeat:true
       onTriggered: {
           // this fun will call every second
           communicationbwleapHMI.getfun2();
       }
   }
}


Using timer for polling this is not a very good idea. You should make your own Q_PROPERTY-es and defining their NOTIFY signal. That way you can let QML know that something is changed and QML will automatically grab those new changed values. Take a look to this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html

As @Ponzifex mentioned, the best way to handle this is to have your CPP classes notify the QML when the data has changed, rather than polling the CPP every second. But if you still want to poll, what's stopping you from calling both communicationbwleapHMI.getfuns() and communicationbwleapHMI.getfun2() from within the same timer?
